# Filter out blanks from tables in all worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a report that has Dollar amounts attached to Cost codes. I have a list of 300+ cost codes in a table. I have 84 worksheets with the exact same table. I am wanting to use an activex button to filter out all of the blanks from the same column in each worksheet.

```
Private Sub FilterBlanks_Click()

Worksheets("825209000").ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter _
 Field:=4, _
 Criteria1:="<>", _
 Operator:=xlFilterValues

Worksheets("825109202").ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter _
 Field:=4, _
 Criteria1:="<>", _
 Operator:=xlFilterValues

Worksheets("825109200").ListObjects("Table3").Range.AutoFilter _
 Field:=4, _
 Criteria1:="<>", _
 Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

The code attached is what I am using for this. It seems to be working fine, but I am wondering how I would go about making a loop of some kind so I dont have to add each worksheet & table into the code.

Comment: Do you have one table on each worksheet?

Comment: Yes, each worksheet is the exact same format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you read up on loops.

```
Private Sub FilterBlanks_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter _
                                Field:=4, _
                                Criteria1:="<>", _
                                Operator:=xlFilterValues

Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd just add: If ws.ListObjects.Count >= 1 Then to check if the sheet has tables (listobjects)